# retry where script/program left off in python remembering variable value

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling

I would like my script to re-try where it left off when an error occurs.  I am using selenium to download multiple reports.  Once in a while a report will not load correctly.  I want the script, on error, to remember where it was and re-try to pull the report. (I need the script to remember the value of x).

Here is some code that might help...(I desperately need help)

```
import time
import os
import glob
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException

for x in range(1, 51):      
    while True:    
        try:
            fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:/Users//Documents/FirefoxProfile')
            browser = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
            browser.get('https://reportlocation/')

            time.sleep(8)

            browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_UserName").clear()
            browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_UserName").send_keys("ytb971")
            browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_password").clear()
            browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_password").send_keys("Fender25")
            browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_login").click()

#gets user to reporting front end

            ReportMgr= browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Report Manager')
            ReportMgr.click()

            time.sleep(5)

            CustomReport= browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Custom Report')
            CustomReport.click()

            time.sleep(5)

            ProgramManagement= browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management')
            ProgramManagement.click()
            ProgramManagement= browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT)

#pulls reports

            browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management').click()
            time.sleep(10)
            browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN * x, Keys.ENTER, Keys.ENTER)
            time.sleep(30)
            browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ReportViewer1_HtmlOutputReportResults2_CSVButton_ImageAnchor > img").click()
            time.sleep(10)
            browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management').click()
            time.sleep(10)
            browser.quit()

            except:
                continue
            else:
                break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do here is iterate over 50 values of `x`, and as soon as one access fails, you recursively start iterating over all 50 values again. The repeat logic should rather look like this:

```
for x in range(1, 51):
    while True:  # or some condition to put a bound on retries
        try:
            ...
        except:
            continue
        else:
            break
therest()
```

This way, you catch each exception still inside the loop over the 50 values, and you perform retries within your running iteration so remembering the current value of `x` becomes a non-issue. Note the use of `else` with the `try` statement: the `else` clause is executed if no exception occurred; this is when you want to stop retrying with the current value of `x`.

Comment: It is saying that "continue not properly in loop"?

Comment: The continue refers to the `while` loop: If an attempt to access a report fails (raises an exception), continue with the next attempt, still with the same value of `x`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: You still put the `for` loop over the 50 values of `x` inside the `while` loop that retries failed attempts. This way, each retry consists of a whole new loop over the 50 values of `x`.

Comment: Ok - still not working - it is showing a syntax error for the "except".  I appreciate the help and I feel as if we are getting close!  I have uploaded the new script I am working with above.

Comment: The syntax error is due to indentation, unless that got corrupted on its way to the web. Please don't get me wrong but I get the feeling that you should either read up on Python basics or pay a little closer attention when editing your code.

Comment: That hurts.  Have been modifying and reading for a little over a week now on this.  I appreciate the help.  I will continue to work on the indents and try to figure this out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105746/discussion-between-thomas-lotze-and-yogwhatup).

Answer (score 0):

You could write the current value of x to a file in the current directory, and then remove the file when the script is done.  When the script starts up, if the file is still there, then you know that there was an error because the file wasn't removed.  So, read the file to get x and start from there.

But overall, a better solution would be to structure your program so that the `while True` loop is above the `for x in range` loop, so breaking out of one report will naturally proceed on to the next report, instead of skipping all the remaining ones.

Comment: Ok, so when the script runs it constantly updates the file to the new value?  If that is the case....is there ANY way you can show me the code for that?